# Django equivalent of sum+case

Tags: django, django-models

I have a bunch of django models

```
class ReviewItem(Model):
  review = models.ForegnKey("Review")
  person = models.ForeignKey("Person")
  category = models.ForeignKey("Category")
  item = models.ForeignKey("item")
  reviewed = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

class Person(Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Category(Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=127)

class Item(Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
  category = models.ForeignKey("Category")
```

(As you can see, the "Category" fk in ReviewItem is redundant)

There will be at most NxM ReviewItem records where N is the number of people and M is the number of items that they might have assigned to them, and they will have their "reviewed" date set after they've been reviewed.  Items are grouped into categories.

What I want is a count of how many items for each item have been reviewed and how many have not.  In SQL, I could do

```
select category.name, item.name,
sum(case when reviewed is null then 1 else 0 end) as un_reviewed
sum(case when reviewed is null then 0 else 1 end) as reviewed
from reviewitem
join  category on category.id = reviewitem.category_id
join  item on item.id = reviewitem.item_id
group by category.id, item.id
order by category.name, item.name
```

I can't figure out how to do this without doing two separate QuerySets in django.

Doing it with two QuerySets, I ended up with:

```
uncompleted_items = Item.objects.filter(
    reviewitem__review=current_review,
    reviewitem__person__reports_to=eff_user,
    reviewitem__reviewed__isnull=True
).select_related(
    'category',
).annotate(num_uncompleted=Count('reviewitem'))

completed_items = Item.objects.filter(
    reviewitem__review=current_review,
    reviewitem__person__reports_to=eff_user,
    reviewitem__reviewed__isnull=False
).select_related(
    'category',
).annotate(num_completed=Count('reviewitem'))
```

Comment: To clarify. Are you looking for the number of reviewed and unreviewed Items for each *Category*? Or the number of Reviews for each Item? Do you just want the counts or do you want a queryset of model objects?

Comment: I want the number of `ReviewItems` that have the `reviewed` date set and the number that do not have the `reviewed` date set for each `Item`, but I also want the Item and Category model objects (or at least a couple of fields from each).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's less than convenient to do so, it's not impossible with the Django ORM to do this :)

Ok, the hacky solution didn't work so here's the pretty solution ;)

```
from django.db import models
from test_models.models import ReviewItem


class CountNullSql(models.sql.aggregates.Count):
    sql_template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(field)s IS NULL)'


class CountNotNullSql(CountNullSql):
    sql_template = '%(function)s(%(distinct)s%(field)s IS NOT NULL)'


class CountNull(models.Count):
    sql = CountNullSql

    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        aggregate = self.sql(
            col,
            source=source,
            is_summary=is_summary,
            **self.extra)
        query.aggregates[alias] = aggregate

    def _default_alias(self):
        return '%s__%s' % (self.lookup, self.sql.__class__.__name__.lower())

    default_alias = property(_default_alias)


class CountNotNull(CountNull):
    sql = CountNotNullSql


items = (ReviewItem.objects
    .values(
        'item__category__name',
        'item__name',
    ).annotate(
        unreviewed=CountNull('reviewed'),
        reviewed=CountNotNull('reviewed'),
    )
)


# Just debug stuff from here on, might be useful for others :)    
sql, params = items.query.sql_with_params()

try:
    import sqlparse
    sql = sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True)
except ImportError:
    pass

try:
    from pygments import highlight
    from pygments.lexers import SqlLexer
    from pygments.formatters import Terminal256Formatter
    sql = highlight(sql, SqlLexer(), Terminal256Formatter(style='colorful'))
except ImportError:
    pass

print sql
```

The resulting query:

```
SELECT "test_models_category"."name",
       "test_models_item"."name",
       COUNT("test_models_reviewitem"."reviewed" IS NULL) AS "unreviewed",
       COUNT("test_models_reviewitem"."reviewed" IS NOT NULL) AS "reviewed"
FROM "test_models_reviewitem"
INNER JOIN "test_models_item" ON ("test_models_reviewitem"."item_id" = "test_models_item"."id")
INNER JOIN "test_models_category" ON ("test_models_item"."category_id" = "test_models_category"."id")
GROUP BY "test_models_category"."name",
         "test_models_item"."name"
```

Example result:

```
[{'item__category__name': u'cat a',
  'item__name': u'aa',
  'reviewed': 1,
  'unreviewed': 1},
 {'item__category__name': u'cat a',
  'item__name': u'ab',
  'reviewed': 1,
  'unreviewed': 1},
 {'item__category__name': u'cat b',
  'item__name': u'ba',
  'reviewed': 1,
  'unreviewed': 1},
 {'item__category__name': u'cat b',
  'item__name': u'bb',
  'reviewed': 1,
  'unreviewed': 1}]
```

**Update from Paul Tomblin**
The CountNull and CountNotNull methods as described didn't work (evidently booleans count as 1 whether they're true or false), so I changed them as follows:

```
from django.db import models


class CountNullSql(models.sql.aggregates.Sum):
    sql_template = '%(function)s((%(field)s IS NULL)::integer)'


class CountNotNullSql(CountNullSql):
    sql_template = '%(function)s((%(field)s IS NOT NULL)::integer)'


class CountNull(models.Sum):
    sql = CountNullSql

    def add_to_query(self, query, alias, col, source, is_summary):
        aggregate = self.sql(
            col,
            source=source,
            is_summary=is_summary,
            **self.extra)
        query.aggregates[alias] = aggregate

    def _default_alias(self):
        return '%s__%s' % (self.lookup, self.sql.__class__.__name__.lower())

    default_alias = property(_default_alias)


class CountNotNull(CountNull):
    sql = CountNotNullSql
```

Comment: Sorry about the "maxLength" - I was actually typing that from memory.

Comment: No worries :) Is this answer roughly what you are looking for or do you need something else? There are multiple ways of doing this but I think this is the easiest method.

Comment: I'll give it a try in the morning and let you know.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work - even fixing the problem (missing `END` in the `CASE` statement - my fault from the question), it turns out that PostgreSQL doesn't like aggregates in the group by clause.

Comment: Hmm... back to the drawing board I guess, I'll get back to you :)

Comment: Does this return objects, or a dict?

Comment: Since it's an annotation it will return a dict. If you want objects instead the `aggregate` method should be used.

Comment: The `COUNT` on the `IS NULL` is a guess btw, if it doesn't work properly than the case is still an option. But an alternative solution would be (for postgres) to do this: `SUM((field IS NULL)::integer)`

Comment: Finally got some test data, and now I can attest that `COUNT` isn't working, so I'm switching to the `SUM` solution.

Answer (score 11):

With Django 1.8, this can be done using [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/).

So your example query might look like this:

```
from django.db.models import When, Case, Sum, IntegerField

items = Item.objects.annotate(
    un_reviewed=Sum(Case(When(reviewed__isnull=True, then=1)
                         When(reviewed__isnull=False, then=0),
                         output_field=IntegerField())),
    reviewed=Sum(Case(When(reviewed__isnull=True, then=0)
                      When(reviewed__isnull=False, then=1),
                      output_field=IntegerField())))
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done directly with in-built support in Django 1.8. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
params = {'ri_table': ReviewItem._meta.db_table, 'i_table': Item._meta.db_table}
reviewed_query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %(ri_table)s WHERE %(ri_table)s.item_id=%(i_table)s.id AND reviewed IS NOT NULL' % params
unreviewed_query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM %(ri_table)s WHERE %(ri_table)s.item_id=%(i_table)s.id AND reviewed IS NULL' % params
items = Item.objects.extra(select={'reviewed': reviewed_query, 'unreviewed': unreviewed_query})
```

This returns a queryset of Items that are essentially annotated with the count of reviews and unreviews. Each Item is a model object so from there you can get the Category and so on. `print items.query` will show you the SQL statement, but of course further Django magic happens to build the Model instance objects.

Collecting all this data in a single query is not elegant with the Django ORM (to be fair, it's also non-trivial SQL). It's complex enough that I don't think it's worth doing, at least not initially. Simpler code in the Django ORM paradigm will be easier to understand, faster to code and more maintainable. It may (or may not) require more hits to the database but such worry may be premature optimization. Such things as schema normalization may net you greater performance gains. Depending on your use, grabbing the counts like this may actually be faster.

```
reviewed = item_obj.reviewitem_set.exclude(reviewed__isnull=True).count()
unreviewed = item_obj.reviewitem_set.filter(reviewed__isnull=True).count()
```

Comment: Have you gotten a chance to try this? Let us know what worked.

Comment: I seriously doubt doing 'select count' subquery is going to be optimal.

Comment: I agree a select count may not win any speed contests, but this is a solution or at least a starting point. You offer a snippy response to someone helping you...I wonder why.

Comment: It's not a snippy response, it's a reason why I think the answer that was already offered before you wrote you answer is better.

Comment: Okay fair enough. Getting the best, most appropriate answer is the goal. Cheers.